# htaccess reposition a part of a url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello I have a website that should be available in multiple languages. I made it with wordpress. What I am trying to achieve is that every language get its own (virtual) subdomain. So for example fr.foo.eu and nl.foo.eu.

At the moment i have the urls in the following format:
foo.eu/?lang=nl
foo.eu/?lang=fr

It is possible that there is more content in the url for example:
http://hypnose.eu/hallo-wereld/?lang=nl

And i would like to have my urls the following way using htaccess:

```
 http://nl.hypnose.eu/hallo-wereld/
```

Could you guys help me with achieving that.

Here is what i have so far in my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([a-z]{2}\.hypnose\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?]*)\?lang=([a-z]{2})&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ http://%2.hypnose.eu/%1?%3 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]{2})\.hypnose\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?lang=%2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the `.htaccess` that you have so far? That would be great so we can provide some help. Thanks!

Comment: @milz Yes ofcourse, i added it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding, above your wordpress rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^([a-z]{2})\.foo\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?]*)\?lang=([a-z]{2})&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ http://%2.foo.eu/%1?%3 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)lang=
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]{2})\.foo\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?lang=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But it does not seem to work, the url still remains the same. I added the lines you gave me after RewriteBase /. And i deleted the rule: RewriteRule ^/nl/. Any other idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: @Jantje what URL are you entering and what do you expect to happen. When you "**rewrite**", that's when you enter a url like:  `http://nl.hypnose.eu/hallo-wereld/` into the browser's address bar, and the rules "rewrite" it to: `/hallo-wereld/?lang=nl`.

Comment: For example i want: http://foo.eu/hallo-wereld/?lang=fr to show in the adress bar as http://fr.foo.eu/hallo-wereld/. But it has to show the content of http://foo.eu/hallo-wereld/?lang=fr. Maybe i was not clear enough, sorry for that

Comment: @Jantje then you're asking for 2 rules, one to redirect the browser, and one to rewrite the request, see edit

Comment: I added your new post, but now I get a 500 internal server error. I also added my current .htaccess file. And do i need to set something else, for example a subdomain alias ?

Comment: @Jantje sorry, left out a `)` in the first condition

Comment: Yes indeed, it is redirecting now. But i still get a 500 internal server error. But we are a step further :) Do you know what else I could check ?

Comment: @Jantje not sure why, I don't get an error. Though the `%2` is supposed to be ` %1` in the last rule. If you still get 500 errors, check your error logs

Comment: What kind of setup did you use to test it, maybe it is different then mine ?

Answer (score 0):

There are popular word press plugin for multilingual which gives setting for URL for current language

1)qTranslate X

2)qTranslate

Try Pre-Domain Mode in plugin.

Comment: Tank you, i know i have currently qTranslate X installed but i get the same problem when i use the pre-domain function. There comes an internal server error 500.